# Как считать с файла .txt рандомную строку PHP

Tags: php

Есть словарь с множеством слов, каждое новое слово начинается с новой строки.
Как можно занести в переменную $words рандомное слово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если файл огромный, чтоб ни читать его весь, не разбивать на строки, не считать количество строк, не выбирать случайную из них. Можно выстрелить приблизительно по строке =)

```
//Имя файла
$FILENAME = "/home/user/text.txt";
//Разделитель строк в файле
$LINE_DELIMITER = "\n";
//Максимальная разумная длина одной строки
$MAX_LINE_LEN = 255 + strlen($LINE_DELIMITER);
//Берем немного с запасом
$TRIPLE_BUFFER = $MAX_LINE_LEN * 3;
//Длина файла
$fileLen = filesize($FILENAME);
//На всякий случай проверим длину файла
if (empty($fileLen) || $fileLen < $TRIPLE_BUFFER) {
   throw new \ErrorException("Файл слишком мал");
}    
//Случайная позиция для чтения
$rnd = rand(0, $fileLen - $TRIPLE_BUFFER);
//Открываем файл для чтения
$handle = fopen($FILENAME, "r");
//Устанавливаем указатель в случайном месте файла
fseek($handle, $rnd);
//Читаем начиная со случайной позиции
$stream = fread($handle, $TRIPLE_BUFFER);
//Разбиваем текст на строки
$lines = explode($LINE_DELIMITER, $stream);
//Считаем количество прочитанных строк
$lineCount = count($lines);
//Инициализируем нашу случайную строку
$randomLine = "";
//Пропускаем первую строку, так как она может быть обрезана
$startAtLine = ($rnd !== 0) ? 1 : 0;
//Ищем случайную строку
for ($i = $startAtLine; $i < $lineCount; $i++) {
    //Пропускаем пустые строки
    if (!empty($lines[$i])) {  
        //Ну и наконец, вот наша случайная строка
        $randomLine = $lines[$i];
        break;    
    }
}
```